# AngularJS Directive Not Contained In Parent Element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Im trying to create a basic directive that puts an image on the page.  The image is contained in a

tag that may or may not be shown depending on a ng-show value.  so, something like

```
<p ng-show="showImage">
  <imageDir></imageDir>
</p>
```

The directive works fine, but it never actually stays within the

tag, and it will be shown all the time, regardless of the value of showImage

Can anyone tell me why?

Here's a plunkr that shows the issue
http://plnkr.co/edit/gPXezknXe2mBYztm9QO2?p=preview

Comment: "The `P` element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself)." [reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `<p>` to `<div>` and it works fine: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UagkqnJEpCtwarpMWwj7?p=preview).

---

`<p>` only accepts so called [`phrasing content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) and your directive -- for obvious reasons -- does not belong to this group. So browser just put it outside of the `<p>`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is: putting a `div` in a `p` causes invalid markup. Use inline tag instead , like `span` for example:

```
<p ng-show="false">
    <span gravatar email-hash="09s7dvywoifhowvw5"></span>
</p>
```

Working: http://plnkr.co/edit/VSKq02?p=preview

Comment: Thanks guys both these answers worked .. Wish I could select two answers though

Comment: @Cheyne it is ok , i'm not chasing for reputation :)